# How to extract labels from TensorFlow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a labelled "prediction" dataset and a model.
This is how the dataset is built:

```
image_size = (200, 200)
batch_size = 32

prediction_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=123,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True)
```

What I am trying to do is comparing predicted values to true values to plot a confusion matrix; something like:

```
    prediction = model.predict(prediction_data)
    predicted_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(true_labels, predicted_labels)
    sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap="Blues")
    plt.xlabel("Predicted Labels")
    plt.ylabel("True Labels")
    plt.show()
```

My problem is that I have found no way of easily retrieving `true_labels` from the `prediction_data dataset` object.
Should I loop over each batch and use argmax to read each one-hot encoded label? And if I do that, would I be guaranteed to explore the dataset in the same order as when recovering the prediction results?

Comment: You don't need to shuffle non-training data, and then you can just loop over the dataset.

Comment: You're correct in your approach. Since prediction_data is a tf.data.Dataset object, you'll need to iterate through it to retrieve the true labels. The order should be preserved during iteration, so you can expect consistency between the true labels and the predicted labels.